# roo gwt sample not working

Tags: gwt, spring-roo

I'm trying to create a sample gwt project using roo as given in the link: 
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/roo-sts.html

but When I try to run "script ..\samples\expenses.roo" in Spring roo 
1.1.4 I'm getting the below error:

> "GWT module's gwt.xml file not found; cannot continue"

I'm using the STS downloaded from http://www.springsource.com/products/eclipse-downloads

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug, already reported at Roo's JIRA.  Take a look at [ROO-2445](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-2445).

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer from: [link]http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?109970-Spring-roo-1.1.4-error-in-expenses-sample&p=365009#post365009

Answer (score 1):

Have you already import project to eclipse?
in console mode go to your directory of expenses.roo, type:

> > Roo
> >     gwt:run
> >     perform eclipse

then open STS and follow these steps

> > Import
> >     Existing Projects into Workspace
> >     Choose Expenses directory
> >
> > Right click on Expenses
> >     Google >> WebToolkit settings >> Use Google Web Toolkit checked

Perhaps Maven >> Enable dependency Management

Finally:

> > Run as >> Web Application

Comment: roo script is not executing successfully 
`script ..\samples\expenses.roo`

Comment: if you´re using roo shell, you have to add Path variables. If you haven´t done that before. I´m going to show you my variables. JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6; ROO_HOME=C:\springsource\spring-roo-1.1.2.RELEASE\bin;MAVEN_HOME=C:\springsource\maven-2.2.1.RELEASE. Then go to System Variables change the Path, like adding java_home, roo_home and maven_home complete path. Then it should work

Comment: Thank you for the video, but still no use - same error `GWT module's gwt.xml file not found; cannot continue` 

. I'm using roo 1.1.4 and GWT 2.3 ... btw, what is the software you've used to make the youtube video?

Comment: Looks like there is some issue [link](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-2445) in roo 1.1.4

Comment: STS with Roo Maven, latest version. GWT SDK 2.3 and nothing else. IN EClipse you´ve to go to Google >> WEbtoolhit Settings >> Check Use GWT. Try to run >> Web Application. If it shows errores delete all Gae Stuff. Then go to Maven >> Update Dependencies >> Run as Web Application